# Android ContentResolver how to specify the sort order?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I am trying to sort alphabetically mp3 files in correct order but no success.
I tried using different sort order and it doesn't work.

```
List<Uri> listUriSub = new ArrayList<>();
ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
Timber.tag("SUB_FOLDER_NODE").e(" %s", rootUri.getPath());
String sortOrder = DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME + " DESC";
String sortOrder2 = DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(rootUri, new String[]{
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE},
        null, null, sortOrder2);
try {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        final String docId = c.getString(0);
        final String name = c.getString(1);
        final String mime = c.getString(2);
        // Timber.tag("SCAN_FILE_ID").e( "docId: " + docId + ", name: " + name + ", mime: " + mime);
        Timber.tag("FILE_ORDER_NAME").e(name);
        //IS DIRECTORY
        if (isDirectory(mime)) {
            final Uri newNode = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, docId);
            // Timber.tag("FOLDER: ").e(name);
        }
        //IS FILE
        else {
            Timber.tag("FILE: ").e(name);
            if (name.contains(".mp3") || name.contains(".MP3")) {
                final Uri newNode = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, docId);
                listUriSub.add(newNode);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exampe OTPUT 1

```
02a_WP_Druzyna_Pierscienia_Prolog_O_fajkowym_zielu.mp3
01a_WP_Druzyna_Pierscienia_Prolog_W_sprawie_hobbitow.mp3
01b_WP_Druzyna_Pierscienia_Prolog_W_sprawie_hobbitow.mp3
```

Should be

```
01a_WP_Druzyna_Pierscienia_Prolog_W_sprawie_hobbitow.mp3
01b_WP_Druzyna_Pierscienia_Prolog_W_sprawie_hobbitow.mp3
02a_WP_Druzyna_Pierscienia_Prolog_O_fajkowym_zielu.mp3
```

Exampe OTPUT

```
02_metro_2035.mp3
05_metro_2035.mp3
03_metro_2035.mp3
04_metro_2035.mp3
01_metro_2035.mp3
```

Should be

```
01_metro_2035.mp3
02_metro_2035.mp3
03_metro_2035.mp3
04_metro_2035.mp3
05_metro_2035.mp3
```

The problem could be "_" in title or numbers ?

Comment: Please tell value of rootUri.toString(). Where did you get this uri from? Please remove Content Provider from the title of your post. You are not programming a content provider but a content consumer.

Comment: Considering the 2nd example, at a guess, it could be that the order is being ignored and that it may be that the underlying sort is thus according to no order (i.e. however the query optimiser determines the row order). Perhaps the issue is with what appears to be the query method in the **ContentResolver** class, which would appear to then invoke the SQliteDatabase query method. Perhaps  the order is being ignored therein.

Comment: root folder is URI from android SAF /tree/primary:Download/AudioBooks. Method list mp3 files from selected folder

Comment: I didn't find a solution to the problem, but I found a workaround. After the while is finished, you can sort the list using: listUriSub = Collections.sort(listUriSub)  and return sorted list, or if someone use Map listUriSub = new TreeMap<Uri, String>(listUriSub);